# CMake glob list of files without directory path

Tags: c++, cmake, glob

If you glob a list of files with `file(GLOB..)` in CMake, the files are all listed with their full path attached.

How can I glob a group of files in CMake saving only the name of the files?

I read the [official manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) and here I found this:

```
 file(GLOB <variable>
 [LIST_DIRECTORIES true|false] [RELATIVE <path>]
 [<globbing-expressions>...])
```

and

```
 By default GLOB lists directories - directories are omitted in result 
 if LIST_DIRECTORIES is set to false.
```

I tried these solutions, but none of them works:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE src_files LIST_DIRECTORIES false ${SRC})

file(GLOB_RECURSE src_files LIST_DIRECTORIES=false ${SRC})

file(GLOB_RECURSE src_files LIST_DIRECTORIES(false) ${SRC})

set(LIST_DIRECTORIES false)
file(GLOB_RECURSE src_files ${SRC})
```

My output is always the list of the files with full path attached. I know I could use RELATIVE to set the path accordingly, but I would prefer to avoid it if I can.

Comment: And why is using the full path a problem? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: "I know i could use RELATIVE to set the path accordingly, but i would prefer to avoid it if i can." - But *RELATIVE* is the exact way for strip directory component from the resulted path. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: The actual problem is that i need to glob a group of files (from different folders) and symbolic link them into one folder. I want to avoid RELATIVE because i would need to create a lot of file(GLOB...) and i don't think it's very good.

Comment: Oh, so using *GLOB_RECURSE* is intentional. You cite signature of `file(GLOB)`, so I thought that you use `file(GLOB_RECURSE)` in your code by accident.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LIST_DIRECTORIES` is used to include/exclude directories in your results in situation when given location `${SRC}` contains both files and directories.

If you want to get rid of path, use `foreach` along with `get_filename_component` on results from `file(GLOB_RECURSE...)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's really great!
now it works just fine!

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE LIST_DIRECTORIES false src_files ${SRC})
```

Documentation is erroneous, `LIST_DIRECTORIES` comes before variable

Comment: This stores the list of files inside `LIST_DIRECTORIES` variable. The documentation is correct.